# RequestFactory doesn't populate all fields of my entity proxy

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, gwt2

Could you please tell me how I can make RequestFactory populate fields of my entity proxy that are entity proxies too ?

Here is parent proxy

```
@ProxyFor(value = Organization.class, locator = PojoLocator.class)
public interface OrganizationProxy extends EntityProxy
{
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
    public String getAddress();
    public void setAddress(String address);
    public PersonProxy getContactPerson();
    public void setContactPerson(PersonProxy contactPerson);
}
```

as you can see it contains another proxy as field. Here is how PersonProxy looks like

```
@ProxyFor(value = Person.class, locator = PojoLocator.class)
public interface PersonProxy extends EntityProxy
{
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
    public String getPhoneNumber();
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
    public String getEmail();
    public void setEmail(String email);
    public OrganizationProxy getOrganization();
    public void setOrganization(OrganizationProxy organization);
}
```

In my `RequestContext` interface I have method `Request<OrganizationProxy> findOrganizationById(long id)`. DAO class that fetches real Organization from datastore sets  its `contactPerson` field but in the client it's always `null`. In fact RequestFactory never even calls Organization.getContactPerson().

My client call looks like this

```
createFactory().contextOrder().findOrganizationById(1).fire(new Receiver<OrganizationProxy>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(OrganizationProxy response)
    {
        if (response == null)
        {
            organizationProxy = orderRequestContext.create(OrganizationProxy.class);
            organizationProxy.setContactPerson(orderRequestContext.create(PersonProxy.class));
        } else
            organizationProxy = orderRequestContext.edit(response);

        // Copy the data in the object into the UI
        driver.edit(organizationProxy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(ServerFailure error)
    {
        createConfirmationDialogBox(error.getMessage()).center();
    }
});
```

What am I missing here ? Shall I do something somewhere manually ? Isn't RequestFactory supposed to populate whole graph ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but I found the answer. I should have RTFM.

> When querying the server, RequestFactory does not automatically
>   populate relations in the object graph. To do this, use the with()
>   method on a request and specify the related property name as a String