# Choosing between SimpleBeanEditorDriver or RequestFactoryEditorDriver in the context of transferring full object graph

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I'm new to RequestFactory so please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

I wrote sample project that uses RequestFactory with Objectify on server-side.

I used [SimpleBeanEditorDriver](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/editor/client/SimpleBeanEditorDriver.html) in client-side but then I got confused with problem of dealing with full graph of my object. I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459589/requestfactory-doesnt-populate-all-fields-of-my-entity-proxy) that has snippets of my code with entities.

After some experiments I found following:

- SimpleBeanEditorDriver requires `with()` to fetch full graph of the
  object but surprisingly doesn't need it when I'm sending object from client to
  server.
- RequestFactory requires me to use `with()` in both cases but has
  convenient method `getPaths()` so I don't need to hardcode anything
  in my code. Names of fields tend to change :)

Is there a way to use SimpleBeanEditorDriver without hardcoding names of entire graph ? It can automatically send entire graph to server but why not do the same when getting it from the server ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use SimpleBeanEditorDriver without hardcoding names of entire graph ?

No, unless you replicate `RequestFactoryEditorDriver`'s `getPaths()` functionnality (that can be done with an `EditorVisitor`, that's exactly what `RequestFactoryEditorDriver` does under the hood)

> It can automatically send entire graph to server but why not do the same when getting it from the server ?

Request Factory and the Editor framework don't know each other. The `RequestFactoryEditorDriver` knows Request Factory (automatically `edit()`s proxies, provides a convenient `getPaths()`, and historically was the only one to provide a `setErrors`, before `setConstraintViolations` was retrofitted into a base `EditorDriver`), but Request Factory doesn't know the Editor framework.
So, you can't say one *can send […] to server*, or that one driver *“requires `with()` to fetch full graph”* and the other *“requires `with()` in both cases”*: Request Factory requires `with()` to fetch proxy relationships, and `with()` isn't involved wrt what is sent to the server (only what's retrieved); and that's nothing to do with the Editor framework.

Comment: I see. Could you please elaborate more on how exactly I can extend `SimpleBeanEditorDriver` so that it has `getPaths()` functionality ?