# RequestFactoryEditorDriver doesn't save full graph even though "with()" is called. Is circular reference an issue?

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, gwt2

Could you guys please help me find where I made a mistake ?

I switched from SimpleBeanEditorDriver to RequestFactoryEditorDriver and my code no longer saves full graph even though `with()` method is called. But it correctly loads full graph in the constructor.

Could it be caused by circular reference between OrganizationProxy and PersonProxy ? I don't know what else to think :( It worked with SimpleBeanEditorDriver though.

Below is my client code. Let me know if you want me to add sources of proxies to this question (or you can see them **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459589/requestfactory-doesnt-populate-all-fields-of-my-entity-proxy)**).

```
public class NewOrderView extends Composite
{
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, NewOrderView> {}
    private static Binder uiBinder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    interface Driver extends RequestFactoryEditorDriver<OrganizationProxy, OrganizationEditor> {}
    Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);

    @UiField
    Button save;

    @UiField
    OrganizationEditor orgEditor;

    AdminRequestFactory requestFactory;
    AdminRequestFactory.OrderRequestContext requestContext;

    OrganizationProxy organization;

    public NewOrderView()
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

        requestFactory = createFactory();
        requestContext = requestFactory.contextOrder();
        driver.initialize(requestFactory, orgEditor);

        String[] paths = driver.getPaths();
        createFactory().contextOrder().findOrganizationById(1).with(paths).fire(new Receiver<OrganizationProxy>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(OrganizationProxy response)
            {
                if (response == null)
                {
                    organization = requestContext.create(OrganizationProxy.class);
                    organization.setContactPerson(requestContext.create(PersonProxy.class));
                } else
                    organization = requestContext.edit(response);

                driver.edit(organization, requestContext);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ServerFailure error)
            {
                createConfirmationDialogBox(error.getMessage()).center();
            }
        });
    }

    private static AdminRequestFactory createFactory()
    {
        AdminRequestFactory factory = GWT.create(AdminRequestFactory.class);
        factory.initialize(new SimpleEventBus());
        return factory;
    }

    @UiHandler("save")
    void buttonClick(ClickEvent e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        save.setEnabled(false);

        try
        {
            AdminRequestFactory.OrderRequestContext ctx = (AdminRequestFactory.OrderRequestContext) driver.flush();
            if (!driver.hasErrors())
            {
                // Link to each other
                PersonProxy contactPerson = organization.getContactPerson();
                contactPerson.setOrganization(organization);

                String[] paths = driver.getPaths();
                ctx.saveOrganization(organization).with(paths).fire(new Receiver<Void>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void arg0)
                    {
                        createConfirmationDialogBox("Saved!").center();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(ServerFailure error)
                    {
                        createConfirmationDialogBox(error.getMessage()).center();
                    }
                });
            }
        } finally
        {
            save.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to realize that the problem was the composite **id** of Person entity.

Below is the code snippet of `PojoLocator` that is used by my [proxy entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459589/).

```
public class PojoLocator extends Locator<DatastoreObject, Long>
{
    @Override
    public DatastoreObject find(Class<? extends DatastoreObject> clazz, Long id)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId(DatastoreObject domainObject)
    {
    }
}
```

In order to fetch child entity from DataStore you need to have id of a parent class. In order to achieve that I switched "ID class" for Locator<> to String which represents textual form of Objectify's Key<> class.

Here is how to looks now:

```
public class PojoLocator extends Locator<DatastoreObject, String>
{
    @Override
    public DatastoreObject find(Class<? extends DatastoreObject> clazz, String id)
    {
        Key<DatastoreObject> key = Key.create(id);
        return ofy.load(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String getId(DatastoreObject domainObject)
    {
        if (domainObject.getId() != null)
        {
            Key<DatastoreObject> key = ofy.fact().getKey(domainObject);
            return key.getString();
        } else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Please note that your implementation may slightly differ because I'm using Objectify4.

Answer (score 1):

`with()` is only used for retrieval of information, so your `with()` use with a `void` return type is useless (but harmless).

Whether a *full graph* is persisted is entirely up to your server-side code, which is intimately bound to your persistence API (JPA, JDO, etc.)

First, check that the `Organization` object you receive in your `save()` method on the server-side is correctly populated. If it's not the case, check your `Locator`s (and/or static findXxx methods) ; otherwise, check your `save()` method's code.

Judging from the code above, I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: After multiple experiments I found out that problem is not a choice of editor driver. **Full graph is being saved if I persist new object(s)** but doesn't work if I try to persist entities that were fetched from DataStore and edited in the form. Is it something wrong with contexts or something? Any thoughts?